# Joining of non-unique cells across multiple columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have some personal data with first/last names, e-mails, institutions people work at, etc. There are many, many duplicates because this was collected from a few sources over 2-3 years. Sometimes the same person provided different versions of their name, a different e-mail address, etc. I'd like to have a compact version of this data, where a single person (identified by a PersonID) is listed on a single row, with unique variants of their name, e-mail, etc. listed in each cell. Bonus points if the values in every cell are sorted, but far from required.
[image: Incoming data and expected output]
Example above also available at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jizgysC1dntZHg8pZ0--dSAPevSfyXyiVyenj02GiwQ/edit#gid=0

I'm looking for a way to display the unique values in each column of a filter result, ideally staying away from =QUERY if at all possible.

This is easy to do when working with just one resulting column:

`=FILTER(A4:A9,D4:D9=1)`  -->  `=JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(FILTER(A4:A9,D4:D9=1)))`

...but the moment the filter spits out results in multiple columns:

`=FILTER(A4:C9,D4:D9=1)`  -->  `???`

...I have no clue what to do, other than doing the code above for each column separately (which would be a hassle, given the number of columns involved). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that using `MAP`:

```
=MAP(UNIQUE(D4:D),LAMBDA(id,BYCOL(FILTER(A4:D,D4:D=id),LAMBDA(col,JOIN(CHAR(10),UNIQUE(col))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to solve my problem! Now I just have to dissect it to understand it enough to apply it on my own in other situations :)

Answer (score 1):

By stablishing a column in I with unique values (=UNIQUE(D4:D)), you can use this MAKE ARRAY:

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(I4:I),COUNTA(F3:H3),LAMBDA(r,c,
JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(INDEX(A4:C,,c),D4:D=INDEX(I4:I,r)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work on the size of data I'm working with - I get a "Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula." message... I'll try to decipher how it was constructed and maybe it'll be helpful in less intense scenarios, though :)

Comment: Good luck with your projects!